# okd(openshift) pod not writing result to disk

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, okd

I was successful to containerize mkp224o for vanity v3 onion addresses generation and I am successful running the image from docker directly,but inside my OKD cluster the image starts and I get a running pod that is utilizing the CPU but no results are shown in pod logs or written to disk.

docker run --rm mkp224o -d /tmp f  # generates results locally and on  cluster nodes

if I do **oc edit dc** and add **args:"/onion/mkp224o -d /tmp f"** # no results written/shown

```
#Dockerfile
FROM alpine:3.9

RUN set -ex \
    && cd /tmp \
    && apk add --no-cache tini libsodium pcre2 \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .fetch git make autoconf build-base libsodium-dev pcre
2-dev \
    && git clone https://github.com/cathugger/mkp224o.git --depth 1 \
    && cd mkp224o \ 
    && ./autogen.sh \
    && ./configure --enable-amd64-51-30k --enable-regex \
    && make \
    && mkdir /onion \
    && cp ./mkp224o /onion \
    && apk del .fetch \
    && cd;rm -r /tmp/mkp224o \
    && adduser -g '' -h /onion -u 1000 -D -s /sbin/nologin onion \
    && chown -R onion:onion /onion

USER onion

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini","--","/onion/mkp224o"]
CMD ["-d /tmp filter"]
```

I was expecting since it ran from docker and displayed results that it should do the same on the cluster inside the pod.

Comment: OpenShift by default will not let you run as `onion` user, but an assigned user ID. It will not be able to write to directories if they are only owned by `onion` user. https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/why-do-my-applications-run-as-a-random-user-id.html

Answer (score 0):

Openshift runs containers as random unprivileged user with group 0 (root). You don't need to create user in your Dockerfile, because it is pointless in Openshift.
Instead you must use this commands:

```
RUN chgrp -R 0 /onion && chmod -R g=u /onion
```